# Mongoid pagination

Tags: pagination, mongoid

I tried

```
@posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

and

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```

but neither method works

```
undefined method `page' for Post:Class

undefined method `paginate' for Post:Class
```

How do you do pagination with mongoid?

Comment: Just using some library to pagination with MongoDB. You can use:                                 gem 'will_paginate'  and
gem "will_paginate_mongoid"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use Kaminari https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: I get these same errors when using mongoid. There's no page method.

Comment: did you restart server after rails g kaminari:config?

Comment: Kaminari works perfectly for me with Rails 4.0.0, Mongoid 4.0.0.

Comment: There is a will_paginate_mongoid, but you would need both will_paginate and will_paginate_mongoid to work with both. The ease and simplicity of just using kaminari makes it the superior choice.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => 1, :limit => 10).desc(:_id)
```

`desc(:_id)` is added so that latest posts could be listed first.

Comment: This worked for me after I added `gem 'mongoid-pagination'` to my `Gemfile`.

Comment: Last commit on that project was `May 23, 2017`.

Answer (score 5):

Still using will_paginate is also okay.

This thread has same issue: [undefined method `paginate' for Array on Rails 3 with mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019924/undefined-method-paginate-for-array-on-rails-3-with-mongoid)

The main point to fix the error is to add this line before the controller call paginate library:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

It should be added to default config file if you use mongoid for the whole project.

Hope the explanation helpful.

Reference from origin gem source: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility at "WillPaginate::Collection" section.

P/S: this is just a work around if your query is not very large. If you want better performance, let's try [mongoid-pagination gem](https://github.com/ajsharp/mongoid-pagination), [custom will_pagination gem](https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid) or another pagination gem which supported Mongoid like [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

Comment: I think origin version of will_paginate didn't support no-sql databases like Mongoid so calling the base core of this gem will resolve this issue by consider the database record like normal arrays, not special sql database format like MySQL, SQLite, ...

Comment: This should be the correct answer and not recommending another gem.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but for anyone else looking, I found 'will_paginate_mongoid'

https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid

Really straight forward and lets you simply do

```
collection.skip(20).limit(10)
```

Comment: If for some reason you need to use `will_paginate` and you run `rails-4`, `will_paginate_mongoid` din't work last time I checked.

The solution is to place [mongoid_paginator.rb](https://raw.github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid/master/lib/will_paginate_mongoid/mongoid_paginator.rb) in `app/models/concerns`, remove the outer `module WillPaginateMongoid` and then `include MongoidPaginator` in your model class.

Comment: will_paginate_mongoid doesn't look like it is actively maintained anymore. That last commit on the repo was `Sep 12, 2013`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following gem.

Very helpful.

https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid

Answer (score 2):

To update a bit the answers, now exists the [Pagy](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy) gem, also much more performant (cpu/mem) than will_paginate and kaminari. This is a [migration guide](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/migration-guide)

Answer (score 1):

silly thing, but it worked for me in sinatra after i added require 'mongoid-pagination'
 to app.rb

Comment: ~ 1 year since, I prefer kaminari

Answer (score 1):

Posting several years later, in case someone else faces the same challenge.

`kaminari-mongoid` was released in 2016, and is currently maintained.

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari-mongoid

All the goodness of Kaminiari for Mongoid, including appropriate handling of `Mongoid::Criteria` results, which was possibly the cause of the OP's error.

Comment: Does that work with Mongoid 7.X? It doesn't work for me. Always getting back `undefined method page`.

Comment: I would migrate to Pagy gem. Kaminari performance & mem. usage is even worse than will_paginate_mongoid, [see here](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagination-comparison/gems.html)