# undefined method `paginate' for Array on Rails 3 with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, pagination, will-paginate, mongoid3

Trying to use [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

My Gem file has:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'
```

My orders_controllers.rb:

```
def index
    @orders = Order.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @orders }
    end
  end
```

On my index.html.erb I've put:

```
<%= will_paginate @orders %>
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#index

undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007f79a1be62f8>
Rails.root: /home/askar/Dropbox/rails_studio/somics

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I now there's kaminari gem for pagination, but I want to know about will_paginate.

Comment: did you ran bundle install after you added the gem to your gemfile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array functions are disabled by default you have to enable them by requiring them in your WillPaginate file:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Comment: Not really a tutorial, but look at this website: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility

Comment: Thanks. I've created will_paginate_extensions.rb with require 'will_paginate/array' and put it under config/initializers as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13187461/1745902

Answer (score 2):

In your config/initializers add will_paginate_array_fix.rb file
and in 
will_paginate_array_fix.rb file add

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that after you do as the previous answer suggests:

In your config/initializers add will_paginate_array_fix.rb file and in will_paginate_array_fix.rb file add

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

You need to restart your server in order for that to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to add any files in the config/initializers. Just after doing all the steps as mentioned on the official github page **restart the rails server** and all will work fine.