# Pagination using ROR with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, mongoid

```rb
class Service 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  include Mongoid::Search 
  include Mongoid::Pagination 
  field :name, type: String
end
```

My controller

```
@services = Service.where(active: true).per_page(10)
```

the gem `mongoid-pagination`

The index.html.erb

```
<% paginate @services %>
```

The problem

> undefined method `total_pages' for

The documents
https://github.com/ajsharp/mongoid-pagination

I need to solve the problem with paginate.

Comment: can you share your code from model as well @carlos-lima

Comment: class Service
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Search
 include Mongoid::Pagination
 

 field :name, type: String

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link if its a test project ?, Also can you try  `@services = Service.per_page(10)` and post output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I've found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287946/1678507

> kaminari-mongoid was released in 2016, and is currently maintained.
>
> https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari-mongoid
>
> All the goodness of Kaminiari for Mongoid, including appropriate
>   handling of Mongoid::Criteria results, which was possibly the cause of
>   the OP's error

And in context of OP's question:

```
Movie.page(2).total_pages #=> 1
```